# Jacobian and Hessian of inverse norm of linear map

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, jacobian, hessian-matrix

$f(x) = \frac{1}{\lVert Cx \rVert_2^2}$ so $\nabla f(x) = \frac{-2 C^T C x}{\lVert C x \rVert_2^4}$ if I am not mistaken. But now, if I apply the quotient rule or the product rule to $\nabla f(x)$ to obtain the hessian I get a sum of a matrix and a vector. Can somebody tell me what I did wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: I made a small mistake in my answer which I have now corrected: $\nabla x^T$ isn't the divergence, and actually gives you an identity matrix. Fixing this just removes the $n$ in the final answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand\trans[1]{#1^{\mathrm T}}
$

Assuming the "quotient rule" and "product rule" make sense is not a good idea; these, as usually thought of, are just things from single-variable calculus.

There is, however, a sort of "generalized product rule" we can use. I assume that what you want is the Hessian matrix; the operator that takes a scalar function to its Hessian is $\nabla\trans\nabla$, so we need to take the transpose of your gradient
$$
  \trans\nabla f(x) = \frac{-2\trans x\trans CC}{||Cx||_2^4}
$$
and apply $\nabla$. This looks like
$$\begin{aligned}
  \nabla\frac{-2\trans x\trans CC}{||Cx||_2^4}
    &= \dot\nabla\frac{-2\trans{\dot x}\trans CC}{||Cx||_2^4}
      + \dot\nabla\frac{-2\trans x\trans CC}{||C\dot x||_2^4}
\\
    &= (\nabla\trans x)\frac{-2\trans CC}{||Cx||_2^4}
      + \left(\nabla\frac1{||Cx||_2^4}\right)(-2\trans x\trans CC).
\end{aligned}$$
Note that $\nabla\trans x = I$, the identity matrix. The dots here indicate *what $\dot\nabla$ is differentiating*, and the *undotted* $x$ in each expression should be thought of as being held constant. What is **very** important is that **the order of multiplication matters**, so we cannot just move $\nabla$ however we please; that is why this sort of dot notation is necessary. What we *can* do is move around scalars and take advantage of associativity, which is how we get the last equality. Continuing with the second term, using the chain rule we get
$$
  \nabla\frac1{||Cx||_2^4}
    = \frac{-4\nabla||Cx||_2}{||Cx||_2^5}
    = \frac{-4\trans CCx}{||Cx||_2^6}.
$$
Putting it altogether and simplifying,
$$
  \nabla\trans\nabla\frac1{||Cx||_2^2}
    = \frac{-2}{||Cx||_2^4}\trans CC
      + \frac8{||Cx||_2^6}\trans CCx\trans x\trans CC.
$$

Comment: Your final expression is wrong because
$$(C^TCx)(x^TC^TC) \;\ne\; (x^Tx)(C^TC)^2$$

Comment: @lynn You are correct, I will edit.

Answer (score 2):

Try using differentials to approach the problem
$$\eqalign{
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\cred#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\cblu#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\cgrn#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\p{\partial}
w &= Cx &\qiq \cred{dw} &= C\,dx \\
h &= w^Tw  &\qiq \cblu{dh} &= 2\,\cred{dw}^Tw &= 2\,dx^TC^TCx \\
f &= h^{-1} &\qiq df &= -h^{-2}\cblu{dh} &= -2f^2\,dx^TC^TCx \\
 &&&&= -2f^2x^TC^TC\,dx \\}$$
$$\eqalign{
g &= \frac{\p f}{\p x} = -2f^{2}C^TCx
 \qquad\qquad\qquad\cred{\big\{{\rm gradient}\big\}}\qquad\quad \\
dg &= -(C^TCx)\,(4f\,df) \;-\; 2f^{2}C^TC\,dx \\
 &= \Big(8f^{3}C^TCxx^TC^TC \;-\; 2f^{2}C^TC\Big)\,dx \\
\frac{\p g}{\p x}
 &= 8f^{3}C^TC\cblu{xx^T}C^TC \;-\; 2f^{2}C^TC
 \quad\cred{\big\{{\rm hessian}\big\}} \\
 &= 2hgg^T \;-\; 2f^{2}C^TC \\
}$$
So that is one way to calculate the hessian.

Note that your gradient is missing a factor of $\;-2$.

Comment: thanks! I don't quite understand the notation, e.g. $dh =2 dw^T w$. why does there suddenly appear the scalar $2$? In $df = -h^{-2} dh$ I understand that this is just a differentiation w.r.t. h so we apply the "exponent rule". But why does $w^T w$ remain? shouldn't it be only $w$?

Comment: The factor of 2 comes from substituting $dh$ into the expression for $df.\:$ The "exponent rule" only applies to scalars, not vectors such as $w$. It also **cannot** be applied to matrices. For example, consider the derivative of a matrix inverse $$d\left(M^{-1}\right) \;=\; -M^{-1}\:dM\;M^{-1}$$

Comment: @Greg you could also arrange the first term in the Hessian as $2 f^{-1} \mathbf{g}\mathbf{g}^T$ to reuse introduced variables.